# Nodejs:Array data not added in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my model `profile.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    educationinfo: [{
        universityname:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        degree:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        coursecompletionyear:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        collegename:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        specialization:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        marks:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        courselevel:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
});

const Profile = module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

This is my `route.js` post function

```
router.post('/addprofiledetails', function(req, res, next) {
  let newProfile = new Profile({
    $educationinfo:[{
        universityname:req.body.universityname,
        degree:req.body.degree
    }]
  });
  newProfile.save((err, profile) => {
    if (err) {
        res.json({ msg: 'Failded to add profiledetails' });
    } else {
        res.json({ msg: 'successfully add profile details' });
    }
  });
});
```

I got success msg in post function but the data not added in mongodb. i don't know where i did mistake .please help me.

In mongoDB I got data like,

```
{
    "educationinfo": [],
    "_id": "5bed14b93a107411a0334530",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want details inside `educationinfo`, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to change schema definition and query.

1.remove required from schema Or apply required to those field that you must provide value.

```
educationinfo: [{
        universityname:
        {
            type: String,
           // required: true
        },
        degree:
        {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        },
        coursecompletionyear:
        {
            type: String,
           // required: true
        },
        collegename:
        {
            type: String,
           // required: true
        },
        specialization:
        {
            type: String,
            //required: true
        },
        marks:
        {
            type: String,
           // required: true
        },
        courselevel:
        {
            type: String,
           // required: true
        }
    }]
```

2.change `$educationinfo` with `educationinfo`

```
educationinfo:[{
    universityname:req.body.universityname,
    degree:req.body.degree
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you marked the properties of `educationinfo` as `required`, you need to provide them when you create an instance of `Profile`. If you don't want to do that you need to remove the `required` property from those properties that you won't be supplying on instance creation like below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    educationinfo: [{
        universityname:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        degree:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        coursecompletionyear:
        {
            type: String
        },
        collegename:
        {
            type: String
        },
        specialization:
        {
            type: String
        },
        marks:
        {
            type: String
        },
        courselevel:
        {
            type: String
        }
    }]
});

const Profile = module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', ProfileSchema);
```

After making those changes, you need to make one more change in your POST route, change `$educationinfo` to `educationinfo`

```
router.post('/addprofiledetails', function(req, res, next) {
  const newProfile = new Profile({
    educationinfo:[{
        universityname: req.body.universityname,
        degree: req.body.degree
    }]
  });
  newProfile.save((err, profile) => {
    if (err) {
       res.json({ msg: 'Failded to add profiledetails' });
    } else {
       res.json({ msg: 'successfully add profile details' });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you insert is incomplete.
The properties in your schema marked as required: true need to be inserted aswell. Because you do not meet the schema requirements, it is failing.

Comment: i can't get it. can u tell breifly?